# Formik setFieldError does not show message or prevent submit

Tags: reactjs, formik

Setting the Formik setFieldError does not show message or prevent submit. Any insight into the reason and how to show the error message added using setFieldError.

example Formik Field component

```
<Field component={CustomInputComponent} name="cinput" />
<ErrorMessage name="cinput" />
```

example of setting the error for cinput (CustomInputComponent)

```
form.setFieldError("cinput", "Error in cinput");
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the `ErrorMessage` component by defining the component it should render to display the message in this way:

```
<Field component={CustomInputComponent} name="cinput" />
<ErrorMessage name="cinput" component={FormInputError} />
```

where `FormInputError` is a `styled-component` defined in another file:

```
export const FormInputError = styled.span`
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    color: ${({theme}) => theme.colors.error};
`;
```